# Qu'est-ce qu'une « file indienne » ?

Tags: étymologie, expressions-idiomatiques

J'ai vu le terme *une file indienne* sur un babillard en ligne. Cela veut-il dire *single file*, qui est la traduction proposée par Google Translate ? Si oui, pourquoi ? Je crois que c'est utilisé en français Québécois, peut-être que ça vient d'Amérique du Nord ? Quelle est l'étymologie de cette expression ?

Comment: I'm not sure that 'babillard' is a word used in french. Did you mean 'chat'?

Comment: I meant 'bulletin board' or 'message board'.

Comment: Then the best translation is 'forum en ligne'.

Comment: @Scorpi0 Well I've seen several references saying that 'babillard' does indeed refer to an electronic message board.

Comment: you are right, I didn't know that, but it is pure Quebecois. In France we used the word forum.

Comment: Well it was a Quebecois message board. ;-)

Comment: It is true that "babillard" is not used at all in France, but it is widely used enough in Canada for us french to understand it. On our side we use to say "forum". PS: the comment above is just brilliant :)

Comment: I'm pretty sure « babillard » can be used too to designate a space on a wall to put adds and messages, and is thus not restricted to electronic communications.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It means people (or sometimes animals or objects) being placed in a line, one after another. It refers to the native americans in the popular image walking in a "file indienne" ^^.

Comment: OK, mais que la question était posée en français, donc il serait préférable de répondre en français...

Comment: Oui mais l'auteur avait l'air de parler anglais, c'est pourquoi j'ai répondu en anglais.

Comment: De toutes façons si il a accepté la réponse, c'est qu'il l'a comprise :-)

Answer (score 12):

L'expression d'origine était *à la queue leu leu* mais a [semble-t-il](http://www.expressio.fr/expressions/en-a-la-file-indienne.php) été remplacée au XIX<sup>e</sup> siècle par *en file indienne* ou *à la file indienne* par engouement pour les récits d'Indiens d'Amérique du Nord.

En tous cas, [les deux sont synonymes](http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/file_indienne) et s'appliquent indifféremment à des personnes ou des véhicules.

L'avantage de la *file indienne* est qu'il ne faut pas se demander sans cesse s'il convient ou non de mettre des traits d'union dans *queue-leu-leu* (ou [*queue-leu-leu*](http://www.expressio.fr/expressions/a-la-queue-leu-leu.php), ou [*queue leu-leu*](http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/%C3%A0_la_queue_leu-leu)); sans compter que les Indiens font encore partie de l'imaginaire populaire, au contraire des loups.

Comment: A la queue leu leu c'est un peu connoté "tout le monde s'éclate" (=la chanson), non ?

Comment: Maintenant que je sais que *queue-leu-leu* vient de *leu* (*loup*), je trouverai l'expression moins ridicule.

Answer (score 7):

En France, l'expression *« en file indienne »* s'applique le plus souvent à un groupe de gens, et plus rarement à un groupe d'objets, comme des véhicules.
Cela signifie *« en file, un par un, les uns derrière les autres »*.

On entends aussi parfois l'expression *« à la queue-leu-leu »*, qui en est un synonyme un peu enfantin.

Answer (score 6):

Cette expression vient du fait que, quand les explorateurs étaient en Amérique (ils prenaient celle-ci pour l'Inde), ils virent beaucoup de guerriers qui continuaient dans les mêmes empreintes de pas que les autres.

Ils faisaient cela pour désorienter les ennemis, leur faisant croire, eussent-elles été découvertes, qu'il y avait moins de guerriers qu'en réalité.

---

This expression comes from when the pioneers were in America (which they believed to be the Indian continent), where they say many warriors from various tribes walk this way, following the footprints of other warriors.

They did such thing in order to confuse the enemy (or enemies), make them think that, in case the footprints got discovered, that they were less warriors than they actually were.

Comment: J'ai corrigé un peu, et j'ai laissé le subjonctif (mais il faut le mettre au plus que parfait, et ça devient très soutenu). Il faut comprendre « …, eussent-elles été découvertes, … » comme « …, had they been discovered, … ».

Comment: @Stéphane: Merci beaucoup! Je n'était pas très sûr de ce que j'avais écris... :)